# UICollectionView does resizing when embedded in a container view

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uicontainerview

I have a view with two container views with different background colours. I am using auto layout. Both container views size themselves correctly (going by the colours). The first view just has a button in it and the child view sizes itself correctly and aligns the button as expected.

The second view has a UICollectionView as the top level view does not size itself. The collection view (with a different background colour) seems to flow off the side of the whole screen. It is definitely way bigger that the container view that it is embedded in.

The Container view has "Autoresize children" set (tried it both ways). I've tried different modes for the container: top, scale, aspect fit.

The Collection view has "Autoresize subviews" set (tried it both ways). I've tried various different modes: Scale, top, aspect fit. The collection view has a custom layout but the problem happens whether it is specified or not.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get my UICollectionView to resize itself to match it's parent? I am using Swift it it makes a difference.

I am running XCode 6.4.

Comment: Do you add collection view in the storyboard? What constraints do you set on it?

Comment: @almas - yep, added to storyboard but XCode did not let me change the constraints on it. I can't check now (I'm in Windowsland at work).